# Convert PostgreSQL Query (Function) into Native Query

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I tried to convert the below PostgreSQL Query into a native query but got an error.

Postgres Query:

```
SELECT * FROM find_map('id');
```

Native Query:

```
@Query(value ="Select FUNCTION(find_map, id) from table_name",nativeQuery = true)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: As you are using a native query, you need to use exactly the same syntax , so something like `value = "select * from find_map(:id)"` - I don't know how you pass parameters to such a query.

Comment: Already tried, getting run time error. Server got stopped.
Its not loading repository class at run time

Answer (score 0):

Try to define countQuery

```
@Query(
value = "SELECT * FROM find_map(:id)"
, countQuery  = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM find_map(:id)"
, nativeQuery = true
)
```